# in iOS 10, why "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices" have no use?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios10

In iOS 10, why "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices"  have no use?
when i call this method in ios10 (i'm sure there is at least one peripheral connected by system), it returns 0 elements. but in ios9, it returns some peripheral connected by system!
i don't know why!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Have you tried adding the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key to your Info.plist?

Comment: Yes,  i already adding ..